# How can I customize the search path of symbols when evaluating an expression?

Tags: r, expression, eval, environment

In a case I need to customize the search path of some symbols. For example, when I evaluate an expression `f(x,y,z)`, I need to evaluate it in the following chain of environments:

first, find symbols in `env1` where `x` and `y` are defined, but `f` and `z` are not.

then, find `f` and `z` in `env2` where both are defined.

The problem is that `env1` and `env2` are not defined by myself, that is, their parent environment is determined when I can use them.

For this specific case, I can manually call `exists` and `get` to find those symbols. But this seems not to work in general case where the expression in user-input and unknown in advance.

Is there a general and fast way that work for any user-input expression so that this expression is evaluated within a series of given environment with `inherits = FALSE` except the last one. Suppose the function is named `evalc` then a usage may be:

`evalc(quote(f(x,y,z)), env1, env2, env3)`

where a series of environments are given. For `env1` and `env2`, the symbols are looked for with `inherits = FALSE`; but for `env3` the symbols are looked for with `inherits = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do you really need `inherits = FALSE`?   This works otherwise:

```
esub <- function(...) do.call(substitute, list(...))
evalc <- function(expr, env1, env2, env3 = parent.frame()) {
   eval(esub(esub(expr, env1), env2), env3)
}

 # test
 env1 <- list2env(list(x = 1, y = 2))
 env2 <- list2env(list(f = function(...) list(...), z = 3))
 evalc(quote(f(x, y, z)), env1, env2)
```

2) If you really need `inherits = FALSE` then we copy each environment to a new environment having any empty environment as parent:

```
evalc <- function(expr, env1, env2, env3 = parent.frame()) {
   e1 <- list2env(as.list(env1))
   e2 <- list2env(as.list(env2))
   parent.env(e1) <- parent.env(e2) <- emptyenv()
   eval(esub(esub(expr, e1), e2), env3)
}
```

3) If we have an unknown number of environments:

```
evalc <- function(expr, ..., env = parent.frame()) {
   for(e in list(...)) {
      ee <- list2env(as.list(e))
      parent.env(ee) <- emptyenv()
      expr <- esub(expr, ee)
   }
   eval(expr, env)
}
```

4) Here is another solution that avoids copying.  It does require that you be able to modify the parent of `env1`, `env2`, ...

```
evalc <- function(expr, ..., env = parent.frame()) {
   for(e in list(...)) {
      p <- parent.env(e)    
      parent.env(e) <- emptyenv()
      expr <- esub(expr, e)
      parent.env(e) <- p
   }
   eval(expr, env)
}
```

**Update**  added 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Thanks, what if `evalc(expr, ...)` where `...` is a series of environments? Construct a nested call of `esub()` recursively?

Comment: Thanks for decent solution! One limitation is that if the expression is something like `x <- 1`, it will not do assignment in `env1` but in a copy.